# About on_disconnect callback in Paho MQTT

Tags: python, mqtt

I am using PyQt6 and Paho MQTT in my application. I have written class MqttClient.
in my main application I get the signal `self.ConnectionStatus.emit(f"Subscribed")`
But I am not getting the signal `self.ConnectionStatus.emit(f"Disconnected")` when I call disconnect

```py
        import sys, time
        import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
        from PyQt6.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal

        class MqttClient(QObject):

        messageReceived = pyqtSignal(str)  # Signal to send the received message to the GUI
        ConnectionStatus = pyqtSignal(str)  # Signal to send connection error messages to the GUI

        def __init__(self, broker_host, topic):
            super().__init__()  # Call the base class's __init__ method
            self.client = mqtt.Client()
            self.client.on_connect = self.on_connect
            self.client.on_message = self.on_message
            self.client.on_disconnect = self.on_disconnect  # Add on_disconnect callback
            self.broker_host = broker_host
            self.topic = topic
            
            print("mqtt client: Init done ")

        def connect(self):
            try:
                self.client.connect(self.broker_host, 1883, 60)
                self.client.loop_start()
                print("mqtt client: loop started ")
                self.ConnectionStatus.emit(f"Connected")           
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"mqtt client: Connection error: {str(e)}")
                self.ConnectionStatus.emit(f"error: {str(e)}") 
                raise e  
                
        def on_connect(self, client, userdata, flags, rc):
            if rc == 0:
                #print("mqtt client: Connected to MQTT broker.")
                client.subscribe(self.topic)
                print("mqtt client: Subscribed")
                self.ConnectionStatus.emit(f"Subscribed")
                
            else:
                #print(f"mqtt client: Failed to connect to MQTT broker. Return code: {rc}")
                self.ConnectionStatus.emit(f"{rc}")

        def on_disconnect(self, client, userdata, rc):
            if rc == 0:
                client.close()
                print("mqtt client: Disconnected")
            else:
                self.ConnectionStatus.emit(f"{rc}")
            self.ConnectionStatus.emit(f"Disconnected")

        def on_message(self, client, userdata, msg):
            current_value = msg.payload.decode()
            #print("mqtt client: Received current value: " + current_value)
            self.display_current_value(current_value)
            self.messageReceived.emit(current_value)  # Emit the signal with the received value

        def display_current_value(self, current_value):
            # Update your GUI to display the current value here
            # For example, update a label or text field
            print("Displaying current value: " + current_value)
```

Comment: Is anything logged (if you [enable logging](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/examples/client_logger.py))?

Comment: The on_disconnect is only called when server get disconnected.